# Building a concurrent TableColumnAdjuster for JTable

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jtable, jtableheader

I copied a TableColumnAdjuster class which seems to be pretty popular. 
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/

However, the JTables I am developing are dynamic and can have a large amount of data flow in and out of them (as much as 30,000 records). Obviously, when the TableColumnAdjuster has to iterate through every cell it can take awhile and make the Swing interface unresponsive. I tried putting the adjustColumns() method on its own thread, but the columns began to resize wildly and randomly. Obviously not threadsafe. So I started to reverse engineer the class, turning variables into volatiles, replacing the hashmap with a concurrent hash map, and separating the calculation from the Swing invokeLater() thread.

However, nothing is working and the columns still resize wildly. I'm beginning to wonder if the JTable is not threadsafe altogether. Is JTable even threadsafe for tasks like this? Is there a somewhat simple, strategic insertion of code to make the adjustColumns() run on a separate thread safely? And interact with the Swing thread when it has updates for the view?

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, all modifications to any UI component must be done within the context of the EDT. What you could do is perform the basic calculations in a separate thread, storing the results in a HashMap, and then when synced with the EDT, apply those results. Something like a SwingWorker might help. You could also utilise a "default column value" which would mean you wouldn't need inspect every cell value for each column

Comment: I was a afraid of that, and yes I know Swing is not threadsafe. But ironically you have to multithread to create responsive GUI's. I do understand the EDT itself must contain all view operations on a single thread though.

Comment: The event dispatching thread is responsible for processing the events within the event queue. It has to be done from a single thread, otherwise it would be possible to process events out of sequences (you would get mouse released events before mouse pressed events). Because of this, you should only make modifications to UI elements from within context of the EDT, to ensure that events are not scheduled out of sequence and you are not trying to rely on a state which has yet to be synchronised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't answer your question about making the code Thread safe since it assumes the code is executing on the EDT. I'm not surehow you would restructure the code to use SwingWorkers as the problem is you could still be updating the TableModel while the TableColumnAdjuster is doing its processing.

> large amount of data flow in and out of them (as much as 30,000 records).

With 30K records does the width of each column change drastically from one record to the next AFTER you have determined the initial widths for the initial data?

I mean chances are if you change a cell containing the maximum width, the next greatest width will only be 1 lower given 30K records. So do you really need to change the width lower by 1? The user is not going to worry if the column width doesn't change because as far as they are concerned the largest width could anyone of the other 30K rows.

So, maybe you can get away with using the `onlyAdjustLarger` property. This should only need to look at the current row that was changed to see if the width needs to be increased. Since the user is currently viewing this row it would make sense to increase the width right away.

You would need to modify the `tableChanged(...)` code for this. Instead of invoking `adjustColumns()` all the time you would only invoke it when the `onlyAdjustLarger` property is false. In all other cases you would only need to check the columns and rows that were updated.

Comment: Alright I will play with that. There's pressure to compress columns for screen real estate, but it looks like that comes at a cost especially with dynamic resizing and a large number of records.